# Why is Magento so difficult and what can i expect to work on as a Magento developer?

Tags: magento-1

I saw one question/answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525118/is-magento-development-too-difficult-for-a-junior-developer)**, but it didn't solve my question.

Hi, I am software developer with 2 years of experience.

I worked on 1 project till now which was actually theme customisation project(theme was purchased by the client). When I started learning (in the last 3 months) , I didnt get solid idea of coding in Magento like I had in OOP Php, Cakephp, Codeigniter etc. Still i don't feel like I am solid developer in Magento.

My question is why is Magento difficult for a developer who hasn't worked on Zend framework ?

And 2nd one : What tasks can i expect be working on as a Magento Developer?

P.S. I asked the question on programmer.stackexchange(**[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/281894/why-is-magento-that-much-difficult-and-what-tasks-will-i-be-working-on-as-a-ma)**), but users with high repution told me to ask the question here, to get answer.

Thanks

Comment: Well you're getting close. But since this is a technical forum (i.e. specific reproducible issues) this might not be the best place. 
For that try the Magento forum: http://community.magento.com/

Comment: @SanderMangel , then why do you think this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525118/is-magento-development-too-difficult-for-a-junior-developer) received answers ? Please explain. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: because overflow is a general Magento forum. I'm not trying to send you away, just advising you that from experience I know these kinds of questions get no or low quality answers here

Comment: RUN AWAY! RUN AWAY!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will provide only my humble opinion. It doesn't means that its right at all. I can tell you what was hard for me, and what wasn't hard.

1. Magento has no normal documentation.
2. As written above. Best community is stackexchange.
3. For many people english isn't native language. And understand some articles is not very easy sometimes. Even when author start use different idioms or not common words.
4. If you don't use xDebug forget about low lvl magento development.
5. Even if you are good developer you need rich experience in magento to achieve something not common.

My advice how to improve your magento experience - is to read Certification Preparation Guide. Resolve tasks which are offered.

Here are some of them (randomly):

Q: Describe how Magento determines which controller to use and how to customize route-to-controller resolution

Task: Create your own FRONT controller

Q: Configure a database connection

Q: Describe how to implement advanced Adminhtml Grids and Forms, including
editable cells, mass actions, totals, reports, custom filters and renderers, multiple grids on one page, combining grids with forms, and adding custom javascript to an admin form

In this preparation document most probably you find answer on your second question. You will create new shipping/payment methods, customize everything you see.

Comment: As per Certification guide, is the exam Question ,and lengthy answers type , or its objective type(Select 1 out of 4) ?

Comment: Example of questions you can find in my post. You have a question like 'how does <it> work?' and you are trying to find an answer on this question. Try to google, read code, debug etc...

Answer (score -5):

Magento is an easiest CMS on another one,You can easily do changes on what one already existing in Magento theme, but Customisation is difficult,if you want make a new functionality of your Magento theme you must understand the theme structure otherwise It's not easy.

So select your theme as same as per your Requirement

Comment: I wish I could downvote. I am asking why is it difficult means I want customization , make plugins etc. I am a developer. Please post answers only if you can do it properly.

Comment: Your answer is like -> `Lion is Not dangerous at all` **if you see him from outside the cage**, `but when you are with him in cage` , **it is dangerous**. I am inside the cage playing with Lion, not outside the cage. Please cooperate. Thanks.